# Puppeteer - select element with multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector, puppeteer

I have the following html:

```
<html>

<body>
    <div title="test" class="test">hello</div>
    <input onclick="" type="confusepuppet" value="google" class="button">
    <form action="http://yahoo.com">
        <input onclick="" type="submit" value="yahoo" class="button">
    </form>
    <form action="http://google.com">
        <input onclick="" type="submit" value="google" class="button">
    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

and suppose I want to click the button to redirect to google.com, I can't use value="google" or type="submit", I have to use both value="google" AND type="submit" to avoid clicking the wrong button.

How do I accomplish this in puppeteer?

This doesn't work:

await page.click('input[value="google",type="submit"]')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple value selector:

```js
await page.click('input[value="google"][type="submit"]');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [attribute selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-selectors)

```
const element = await page.$('[value="google"]');
await element.click();
```